# Error on running Jekyll with jekyll-multiple-languages-plugin

Tags: ruby, rubygems, jekyll, jekyll-extensions

I am trying to run Jekyll server on Windows using jekyll-multiple-languages-plugin but I keep getting this error message:

```
C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require': cannot load such file -- jekyll-multiple-languages-plugin (LoadError)
        from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
        from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/jekyll-2.0.3/lib/jekyll/plugin_manager.rb:28:in `block in require_gems'
        from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/jekyll-2.0.3/lib/jekyll/plugin_manager.rb:26:in `each'
        from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/jekyll-2.0.3/lib/jekyll/plugin_manager.rb:26:in `require_gems'
        from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/jekyll-2.0.3/lib/jekyll/plugin_manager.rb:19:in `conscientious_require'
        from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/jekyll-2.0.3/lib/jekyll/site.rb:71:in `setup'
        from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/jekyll-2.0.3/lib/jekyll/site.rb:33:in `initialize'
        from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/jekyll-2.0.3/lib/jekyll/commands/build.rb:26:in `new'
        from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/jekyll-2.0.3/lib/jekyll/commands/build.rb:26:in `process'
        from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/jekyll-2.0.3/lib/jekyll/commands/serve.rb:23:in `block (2 levels) in init_with_program'
        from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/mercenary-0.3.3/lib/mercenary/command.rb:220:in `call'
        from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/mercenary-0.3.3/lib/mercenary/command.rb:220:in `block in execute'
        from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/mercenary-0.3.3/lib/mercenary/command.rb:220:in `each'
        from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/mercenary-0.3.3/lib/mercenary/command.rb:220:in `execute'
        from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/mercenary-0.3.3/lib/mercenary/program.rb:35:in `go'
        from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/mercenary-0.3.3/lib/mercenary.rb:22:in `program'
        from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/jekyll-2.0.3/bin/jekyll:18:in `'
        from C:/Ruby200/bin/jekyll:23:in `load'
        from C:/Ruby200/bin/jekyll:23:in `'
```

I have added the following to the `_config.yml`:
`gems:
- jekyll-multiple-languages-plugin`

Here is a list of my gem files:

```
*** LOCAL GEMS ***

activesupport (4.1.1)
bigdecimal (1.2.0)
blankslate (2.1.2.4)
celluloid (0.15.2)
classifier (1.3.4)
coffee-script (2.2.0)
coffee-script-source (1.7.0)
colorator (0.1)
commander (4.1.6)
execjs (2.0.2)
fast-stemmer (1.0.2)
ffi (1.9.3 x86-mingw32)
highline (1.6.21)
i18n (0.6.9)
io-console (0.4.2)
jekyll (2.0.3)
jekyll-coffeescript (1.0.0)
jekyll-i18n (1.0.2)
jekyll-multiple-languages-plugin (1.2.5)
jekyll-sass-converter (1.0.0)
json (1.7.7)
kramdown (1.3.3)
liquid (2.5.5)
listen (2.7.5, 1.3.1)
maruku (0.6.1)
mercenary (0.3.3)
minitest (5.3.4, 4.3.2)
parslet (1.5.0)
posix-spawn (0.3.8)
psych (2.0.0)
pygments.rb (0.5.4)
rake (0.9.6)
rb-fsevent (0.9.4)
rb-inotify (0.9.4)
rb-kqueue (0.2.2)
rdoc (4.0.0)
redcarpet (3.1.2, 2.3.0)
safe_yaml (1.0.3, 0.9.7)
sass (3.3.7)
syntax (1.2.0)
test-unit (2.0.0.0)
thread_safe (0.3.3)
timers (1.1.0)
toml (0.1.1)
tzinfo (1.1.0)
yajl-ruby (1.1.0 x86-mingw32)
```

I have tried running different versions of Jekyll but with no luck.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Is it possible that this plugin also requires `jekyll-i18n`? Can you add it to `gems` in your _config.yml and try again?

Comment: When I add `jekyll-i18n` to _config.yml I get an error message saying `Unable to activate jekyll-i18n-1.0.2, because jekyll-2.0.3 conflicts with jekyll (~> 1.3.1)` even when I uninstalled the earlier version of Jekyll. I appreciate the help anyway :)

Comment: But to get you right, the `gem list` above was made after you removed other Jekyll versions? Because it isn't mentioning them.

Comment: Yes, once I installed `jekyll-i18n` an earlier version of Jekyll was installed. I removed it and tried again but the same error message appears as if I hadn't removed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you might benefit from the use of a [Bundler](http://bundler.io) `Gemfile` here. It would look like this:

```
source "https://rubygems.org"
gem "jekyll", "~> 2.0"
gem "jekyll-multiple-languages-plugin"
```

Place this in the root of your Jekyll site (where you'd run `jekyll build`). Run `bundle install`, then run Jekyll: `bundle exec jekyll build`. For more information on `Gemfile` and `Gemfile.lock`, check out the [Bundler documentation on the matter](http://bundler.io/v1.6/gemfile.html).