# jekyll-multiple-languages-plugin cannot be found

Tags: ruby, rubygems, jekyll, jekyll-extensions

I'm newbie to Ruby and Jekyll. Recently I've tried to install Jekyll Multiple Languages Plugin onto my GitLab Pages instance. I've managed to successfully add
'gem install jekyll-multiple-languages-plugin
bundle install'

into the *.gitlab-ci.yml* but when I try to add

> gems:
>
> - jekyll-multiple-languages-plugin

into _config.yml in order to use it on the site my commit fails with the following error:

> Using jekyll-watch 1.5.0
>
> Using jekyll 3.4.3
>
> Bundle complete! 3 Gemfile dependencies, 20 gems now installed.
>
> Bundled gems are installed into /usr/local/bundle.
>
> $ jekyll build -d public
>
> Configuration file: /builds/myusername/forty-jekyll-theme/_config.yml
>
> Dependency Error: Yikes! It looks like you don't have jekyll-multiple-languages-plugin or one of its dependencies installed. In order to use Jekyll as currently configured, you'll need to install this gem. The full error message from Ruby is: 'cannot load such file -- jekyll-multiple-languages-plugin' If you run into trouble, you can find helpful resources at https://jekyllrb.com/help/! 
>   jekyll 3.4.3 | Error:  jekyll-multiple-languages-plugin
>
> ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1

I have used this method because any attempt to edit Gemfile ends up in commit error. I've also tried to do all presented steps except adding *bundle install*. In that case I get the same error, but the beginning looks like:

> 18 gems installed
>
> $ gem install jekyll-multiple-languages-plugin
>
> Successfully installed jekyll-multiple-languages-plugin-1.5.1
>
> 1 gem installed
>
> $ jekyll build -d public

I did not manage to find the way to solve it on Stack Overflow nor other sites. [For example this did not help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23757552/error-on-running-jekyll-with-jekyll-multiple-languages-plugin)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the awesome support of allejo from Jekyll's IRC channel I've managed to solve the problem. Here are the steps:

1. I've used *Gemfile*. Now it looks like

   ```
   source 'https://rubygems.org'

   gem 'jekyll'

   group :jekyll_plugins do
    gem 'jekyll-multiple-languages-plugin'
   end
   ```
2. The second modified thing was *.gitlab-ci.yml* (the first line - image: ruby - is also included)

   ```
   image: ruby

   pages:
     stage: build
     script:
   # - gem install jekyll
     - gem install bundler
   # - gem install jekyll-multiple-languages-plugin
     - bundle install
     - bundle exec jekyll build -d public
   # - jekyll build -d public
     artifacts:
       paths:
       - public
     only:
     - master
   ```

It produced a bug, but it was only caused by the lack of declared language which is part of standard plugin configuration.